# Process that works on Ubuntu VM does not work on Ubuntu Docker Image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, docker, container

Basically, I'm installing a python package w/ pip that when run, will search the home directory for a config file and use the information on it to generate and send logs.

I have this set up and working on my Macbook and on a Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox.

Problem: I am trying to do the same w/ a Ubuntu Docker Image but it isn't able to find the config file.

- The directories paths and echo $PATH results are the same b/w the container and vm.
- The config file is placed in /home/user/
- There were no users when I started the Docker container so I created on w/ "useradd -m USERNAME" and gave it sudo.
- I executed the command as the user where the config is located

Is there some fundamental difference b/w VMs and Containers that could be causing this? Did I set up the user incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

In a container, the working directory is not defined by the user you are running the process as. This is because there is no login happening.

Since you are asking for the difference. A VM is emulating a bare metal computer, where you can run an operating system with a kernel and many processes. Some of which are taking care of authentication and setting up the user's environment, such as the initial working directory.

A container on the other hand *contains* 1 or more processes and files, but ussualy does not run a kernel or system managers like systemd. See it more like a glorified chroot environment, where a set of files (in the form of executables, libraries and config) are provided for use. Running anything inside the container still depends on the host's kernel, but it runs in another context. (Google [cgroups](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=cgroups) if you're interested).

So long story short, your working directory in the container is not what you think it is, because nothing is setting it up for you. So you have some choices:

1. Set the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir) directive in the Dockerfile;
2. Do a nasty `cd /home/user && <command>`
3. Use absolute paths for anything you need in the container. Most programs take a command line option for a path to the config file.

Containers are most useful (and I guess its kind of a convention) if you use 1 container for one task. So you can ditch the whole idea of needing to organise files into `/home` and neither run `useradd`. You don't need sudo. The logic in containers is the other way around. It starts as root so that you can build the image and set things up. Later, just before the final command you can drop privileges to a normal user for the remainder of the containers life, ussualy untill the command terminates.

Just dump your config in the root directory (`/`), which is also the default workdir.  Use the [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user) directive to let Docker run the program as that user.

*both links in above paragraph link to different sections of the same page *"Best practices for writing Dockerfiles "*. Which is a good starting point.

**if you need to know the current working path in the container, insert a `RUN pwd` anywhere before your command in the Dockerfile.

**edit**: docker also has an example on how to build a python/pip image:
https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the detailed response. It really helped clear things up. I've got some reading to do on Docker. I ended up running a os.getcwd() and it looks like the default in this container is /root. I had placed the config file in /, which seems to be the root directory for the whole system vs /root which is the home directory for the default user (root in this case). 

One problem solved, another one springs up to take it's place!